# php database table select limited

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im new on php programming and i've searched the function that i need  but didn't found it.
here what exactly i want to do :

- i want to select 2 columns from a table
- set the order by descending by 1 column that is numeric
- and then show in php the first 100 rows that were selected

Here is my code right now php shows all the columns i want it to show the first 100

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pvpkills,char_name FROM characters ORDER BY pvpkills DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['pvpkills'] . "&nbsp " . $row['char_name'];
    echo "<br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT pvpkills,char_name FROM characters ORDER BY pvpkills DESC LIMIT 0,100
```